# Auto create .ndf files based on existing (.mdf (or) .ndf) files sizes

Tags: sql-server

How can I create NDF files automatically in a database, when the size of the existing MDF or NDF exceeds 200GB? My goal would be for larger database, multiple data files to be created automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create additional data files upfront manually and set the main or subsequent secondary files maximum size. SQL Server will not auto-create these data files when one fills up.

You can however write scripts to periodically check the current file usage, using SQL Agent to run and check on a schedule, and write an IF condition to create a new file based on the primary file usage.

This is still not a built-in SQL Server function, yet not impossible to accomplish.

Comment: TSQL or Powershell could also be used for the scripting.